# reversing a Linked List Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

```
struct Node
      {
         int data;
         struct Node *next;
      }
```

I am supposed to reverse a linked list. As on hackerrank, this code works fine.

**CODE A**

```
void rev(Node* head){
    if(head==NULL) return;
    rev(head->next);
    cout<<head->data<<endl;
}
```

**Input:** 2 1 4 5
**Output:** 5 4 1 2

But if I make a following minor change, it breaks, i.e. I get **segmentation fault**!

**CODE B**

```
void rev(Node* head){
    if(head==NULL) return;
    head=head->next;
    rev(head);
    cout<<head->data<<endl;
}
```

**Input:** 2 1 4 5
**Output:** Segmentation fault

But if I do the following change, it works somehow, but doesn't display the first number.

**CODE C**

```
void rev(Node* head){
        if(head->next==NULL) return;
        head=head->next;
        rev(head);
        cout<<head->data<<endl;
    }
```

**Input:** 2 1 4 5
**Output:** 5 4 1

**Question:** Code A and Code B are mostly similar. What's breaking code B?

Comment: In the case of the crash (code B), what if `head->next` is `NULL`? Think about what happens then when you try to print `head->data` after the assignment.

Comment: Why do you care? - the case A works just fine.  -1

Comment: @alex because i wanna break things and find out why :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code 
in Case B:

```
void rev(Node* head){
if(head==NULL) return;
head=head->next;
rev(head);
cout<<head->data<<endl;}
```

Lets have a look in Stack Segment for recursion.

Let `NODE1 -> NODE2->NULL` Where `NODE1 and NODE2` are struct objects.

What your function doing is:

1. Call to `rev(NODE1)`
2. Check if it is NULL
3. Point to `next NODE i.e. NODE2`
4. Call to `rev(NODE2)`
5. Check if It is NULL
6. Point to `next NODE i.e. NULL`
7. Call to `rev(NULL)`
8. Check if It is NULL
9. Pointer will be returned With `head = NULL`

And 
here is the bug i.e. You are accessing `head->data` for the NULL value.

Hope this will Help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you can't access the memory in case **B**. Your pointer points to an address which you didn't allocate (NULL). *By the way, I would suggest making a double linked list. More handy.*

In case **C** you give the function `void rev (Node* head)` a pointer to your list and skip in the second line `head=head->next;` which is your first element. Therefore it does not display in the output of `std::cout`.

***Use case A and you're fine.***

Answer (score 0):

A linked list iterator can only proceed until the end of the linked list.

All linked list iterator code must include a *loop invariant* - a test makes sure that if it's going to *dereference* next, that next is valid.  If it isn't, it stops.  This is usually in the form:

```
if(head==NULL) return;
```

or

```
while(head!=NULL)
```

or

```
if(head->next != NULL) recurse(head->next)
```

if head *is* `NULL`, then it's not safe to do `head->next` (or `head->data` or `head->anything`)

The effect of your changes is to bypass the loop invariant, and look inside `head->next` without checking to see if it is `NULL`.

Specifically, you access `head->data` before checking to see if `head` is null, and **BOOM!**.

It looks you are in /'should I cut the blue wire or the yellow wire'/ territory.  Have fun.

---

While you are not using a loop, recursion is a form of iteration too.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rewrite **Code A** for you:

```
void rev(Node* head){
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        rev(head->next); //recursive call with pointer to next!
        cout<<head->data<<endl; //write after recursive call (reversed)
    }
}
```

**Code B** could be rewritten in the same way:

```
void rev(Node* head){
    if(head!=NULL)
    {
        head=head->next; 
        //head becomes next, but what if next is null, 
        //you try to read next, which is a null pointer here == segmentation fault
        rev(head);
        cout<<head->data<<endl;
    }
}
```

So basically **Code A** does not read the null pointer, but in **Code B** you assign a null pointer to `head` and hence you have to read the null pointer to do this assignment.

In **Code C** the line `if (head->next==NULL) return;` prevents you to use the code below that line in case the next element is null, and hence the current head is not printed.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked list structure is 2->1->4->5->NULL

Code B:

On recursion, when the head has the data=5, head=head->next makes head=NULL , so the next call to rev() returns immediately as head=NULL,now you try to access head->data which is same as NULL->data  which results is segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but whether you have a uni-directional or a bi-directional linked list, if you wish to reverse that list then it is well advisable to maintain both a Head pointer and a Tail pointer:

**In order to reverse a uni-directional linked list, call `Reverse()`:**

```
void Swap(Node* pCurr,Node* pNext)
{
    if (pNext != NULL)
    {
        Swap(pNext,pNext->pNext);
        pNext->pNext = pCurr;
    }
}

void Reverse()
{
    if (pHead != NULL)
    {
        Swap(pHead,pHead->pNext);
        pHead->pNext = NULL;
    }
    Node* pTemp = pHead;
    pHead = pTail;
    pTail = pTemp;
}
```

**In order to reverse a bi-directional linked list, call `Reverse()`:**

```
void Swap(Node* pCurr)
{
    if (pCurr->pNext != NULL)
    {
        Swap(pCurr->pNext);
        pCurr->pNext->pNext = pCurr;
    }
    pCurr->pPrev = pCurr->pNext;
}

void Reverse()
{
    if (pHead != NULL)
    {
        Swap(pHead);
        pHead->pNext = NULL;
    }
    Node* pTemp = pHead;
    pHead = pTail;
    pTail = pTemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code A and Code B are not similar. In code A, you pass `head->next` as the parameter of `rev` without changing the pointer `head`, but in code B, you change the pointer `head`. Therefore, they results differently when calling `cout<<head->data`

your linked list sample can be visualized as: 2->1->4->5->NULL
Your could would be evaluated as (same identation for same scope):
In code A:

```
head: 2,    call rev(head) //your initial call  
    head: 2,    check head==NULL false
    head: 2,    call rev(head->next)
        head: 1,    check head==NULL false
        head: 1,    call rev(head->next)
            head: 4,    check head==NULL false
            head: 4,    call rev(head->next)
                head: 5,    check head==NULL false
                head: 5,    call rev(head->next) 
                    head==NULL, check head==NULL true
                        return
                head: 5,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;  
            head: 4,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
        head: 1,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
    head: 2,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
    return
```

But in code B:

```
head: 2,    call rev(head) //your initial call  
    head: 2,    check head==NULL false
    head: 2,    head = head->next
    head: 1,    call rev(head)
        head: 1,    check head==NULL false
        head: 1,    head = head->next
        head: 4,    call rev(head)
            head: 4,    check head==NULL false
            head: 5,    head = head->next
            head: 5,    call rev(head)
                head: 5,    check head==NULL false
                head: 5,    head = head->next
                head==NULL, call rev(head) 
                    head==NULL, check head==NULL true
                        return
                head: NULL, call cout<<head->data<<endl;  //segmentation fault here
```

Otherwise, in code C:

```
head: 2,    call rev(head) //your initial call  
    head: 2,    check head->next==NULL false
    head: 2,    head = head->next
    head: 1,    call rev(head)
        head: 1,    check head->next==NULL false
        head: 1,    head = head->next
        head: 4,    call rev(head)
            head: 4,    check head->next==NULL false
            head: 5,    head = head->next
            head: 5,    call rev(head)
                head: 5,    check head->next==NULL true
                    return
            head: 5,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
        head: 4,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
    head: 1,    call cout<<head->data<<endl;
    return
```

See that there's three calls to `cout`, so there're only three elements printed.